# API response contains an object(random key value pair) ,how to achieve filtering?

Tags: angular

API response contains an object like:

```
     {
    'prop3': 'value5', 
    'prop2': 'value1', 
    'prop5': 'value4', 
    'prop1': 'value2', 
    'prop4': 'value3', 
  };
```

I'm displaying this in angular material table by subscribing to the response(in service.ts file)..I'm not able to use

```
this.dataSource.filter= filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
```

I'm not able to filter through the data in the mat-table
This is my app.component.ts file

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
      displayedColumns=['select','key','value'];
      dataSource={};
      checked: boolean = false;

      RenderDataTable() {  
        this.apiService.GetAllRecords().subscribe((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource([]);
          this.dataSource=res;
          console.log(this.dataSource);

        });  
      } 

      constructor(public apiService:ApiService){

      }
      applyFilter(event: Event){
        const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
      }
      public refreshlist=()=>{
        window.location.reload();
      }
      ngOnInit(){
       this.RenderDataTable();

      }
 }
```

app.component.html:

```
<!-- Filter -->
<div>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Filter">
  </mat-form-field>
  <button class="marginright" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="refreshlist()">
    <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="refresh">autorenew</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>

<!-- Table -->
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource | keyvalue"  >

  <ng-container matColumnDef="key">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Key </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.key}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value}} </td>
  </ng-container>


  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Please help. I'm trying this out from a long time.

Comment: can you give your object and how you would want it in array?

Comment: Object is like                                                               {
    'prop3': 'value5', 
    'prop2': 'value1', 
    'prop5': 'value4', 
    'prop1': 'value2', 
    'prop4': 'value3', 
  };                                                                I'm able to convert this to array now.                        [{
    'prop3': 'value5', 
    'prop2': 'value1', 
    'prop5': 'value4', 
    'prop1': 'value2', 
    'prop4': 'value3', 
  }]                                                                          But not able to filter through the datasource

Comment: how you want the array to look?

Comment: Run Object.entries(obj)?

Comment: Hi. I'm able to display the object in table but I'm not able to implement filtering

Comment: what kind of filtering you want?

Comment: search filtering

Comment: can you provide screenshot of your grid?

Comment: i posted a method below. convert your object to array from method below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were few problems in your code.

1. First you were not initializing the datasource properly as per material guidelines.
2. You were not mapping your object correctly.
3. your applyFilter code was incorrect.

Corrected Code :-

app.component.html

```
<!-- Filter -->
<div>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Filter">
  </mat-form-field>
  <button class="marginright" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="refreshlist()">
    <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="refresh">autorenew</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>


<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource"  >

  <ng-container matColumnDef="key">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Key </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.key}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value}} </td>
  </ng-container>


  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator 
[length]="length"
pageSize=5
(page)="getPaginatorData($event)"
[pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
showFirstLastButtons="false">
</mat-paginator>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';  
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { PageEvent } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { KeyValue } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  displayedColumns=['key','value'];
  //checked: boolean = false;
  initialDataSource={};
  lowValue: number = 0;
  highValue: number = 20;
  length:number;
  pageIndex:number;
  pageSize:number;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<{key: string, value:string}[]>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;


  originalOrder = (a: KeyValue<number,string>, b: KeyValue<number,string>): number => {
    return 0;
  }
  reverseKeyOrder = (a: KeyValue<number,string>, b: KeyValue<number,string>): number => {
    return a.key > b.key ? -1 : (b.key > a.key ? 1 : 0);
  }
  valueOrder = (a: KeyValue<number,string>, b: KeyValue<number,string>): number => {
    return a.value.toString().localeCompare(b.value);
  }

  RenderDataTable() {  
    this.apiService.GetAllRecords().subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    this.initialDataSource=new MatTableDataSource();
      //this.obj=Array.of(res);
      //console.log(this.obj);
      this.initialDataSource=res;
      const transformedData = [];
      Object.keys(this.initialDataSource).forEach((data) => {
        transformedData.push({'key': data, 'value': `${this.initialDataSource[data]}`});
      })
      console.log(transformedData);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(transformedData);
      this.length=Object.keys(this.initialDataSource).length;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.initialDataSource));

  });  
} 
  constructor(public apiService:ApiService, public http: HttpClient){

  }
  applyFilter(event: Event){
   const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase(); 
  }
  public getPaginatorData(event: PageEvent): PageEvent {
    this.lowValue = event.pageIndex * event.pageSize;
    this.highValue = this.lowValue + event.pageSize;
    return event;
  }
  public refreshlist=()=>{
    window.location.reload();
  }
  ngOnInit(){
   this.RenderDataTable();

  } 
}
```

Working stackblitz :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j8w7bw

Official material link :- https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: I tried this, but I'm not to display data in material table.

Comment: provide a stackblitz please or try to remove keyvalue pipe from your template.

Comment: this application is not launching in stackblitz.

Comment: It's launching now. Can you please check again?

Comment: Thank you so much...This solves my problem..I'm not able to vote your answer as I'm new to stack overflow and I need to have 15 reputations to vote..but thanks a lot!!!